# Couldn't commit processed log positions with the source database due to a concurrent connector shutdown or restart

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am receiving the mentioned warning continuously from Debezium Connector for SQL Server, that I am running by using connect-standalone. At a certain moment, I have tried to start two concurent connectors that connect to the same database, but that was yesterday, and after that I restarted this connector several times, and the other connector is stopped, so I don't know where is that information persisted, and why, because, at the moment only one connector is running, so this shouldn't be logged. As CDC does not work, this seems like a problem, regardless of the fact that it is logged as only a warning, because no (other) error is logged but such lines:

WARN Couldn't commit processed log positions with the source database due to a concurrent connector shutdown or restart (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:238)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem?

Comment: The problem I had with CDC was not related to this annoying and distracting warning which actually could and should have been ignored.